# GCP API for Cloud SQL User doesn't fetch password

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to get information about the users of a specific SQL Database Instance by using the Google.Apis.SQLAdmin API:
The return value contain a List of Users.
User:

```
    {
      "kind": string,
      "password": string,
      "etag": string,
      "name": string,
      "host": string,
      "instance": string,
      "project": string,
      "type": enum (SqlUserType),
      "sqlserverUserDetails": {
        object (SqlServerUserDetails)
      }
    }
```

The "password" field remain null, no matter what I change through the GCP console.
Is there a reason for that? Am I missing a request parameter that will fetch this data?
Tried MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0.
I don't need the password itself I just need to know if there is a password and it exist (also in the .net library the User class contain "PasswordPolicy").
This is the place in console where I add\change the password:
[ImageOfTheConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxPlu.png)

Here you can see the api request and to try it using the right sided "Try This API":

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/users/list

An example of a response I get for user with and a user without password:

```
    {
      "kind": "sql#usersList",
      "items": [
        {
          "kind": "sql#user",
          "etag": etag,
          "name": "noPasswordUser",
          "host": "%",
          "instance": "my-1-test",
          "project": "my-project"
        },
        {
          "kind": "sql#user",
          "etag": etag,
          "name": "withPass",
          "host": "%",
          "instance": "my-1-test",
          "project": "my-project"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Actually there's a Feature Request already for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172487834). Cloud SQL does not store user passwords so it won't be able to return it as-is so the FR asks to return a boolean flag that indicates if a user has a password set or not but that's pending implementation at the moment. The documentation is wrong at this point.

Comment: Wow perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.